# ASUS usb screen is not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: external-monitor

Ubuntu can detect the external usb screen, but it is not working.

```
-> lsusb -d 17e9:
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 17e9:ff0b DisplayLink **ASUSTEK MB169B+**
```

I also followed all the steps from here.
https://teamdynamix.umich.edu/TDClient/47/LSAPortal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=1817

I got the drivers from here https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu-5.6?filetype=exe

Answer (score 2):

The external USB screen MB169B+ works for me now with DisplayLink driver version 5.6.1. It didn't work before with 5.6 for me. So follow these steps:

1. Install the DKMS package:

   ```
   sudo apt install dkms
   ```
2. Download the driver package from the DisplayLink website:
   https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu-5.6.1?filetype=exe
3. Change to the download directory (typically `~/Downloads`):

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
4. Unzip the archive:

   ```
   unzip Display*.zip
   ```
5. Install it as root:

   ```
   sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.6.1-59.184.run
   ```

   You may be asked to install another couple of packages with `apt`, so just answer `Y`/yes.
6. Reboot your machine!

The USB monitor should work now.

`lsusb` command should show the monitor:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17e9:ff0b DisplayLink ASUSTEK MB169B+
```

Your computer may have slow responsiveness if the USB port is not 3.0 or your computer is slow.